# Why ctxpixel isn't drawing images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

So Iam trying to create a minecraft pixelart from minecraft skin like this
so it need alot of cutting
everything is okay except canvasPIXEL isn't doing anything
I tried alot but nothing work the canvas is a bit long
So it's hard to find the problem so I asked here to see if anyone could help me
I used the same code in discord.js but with little differences to work in discord and used
canvas.js (npm)

```
let skinin = document.getElementById("skin");
skinin.addEventListener("change", handleFiles);


function handleFiles(e) {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const canvasFACE = document.getElementById("canvasFACE");
    const canvasFACEH= document.getElementById("canvasFACEH");
    const canvasFACEH2 = document.getElementById("canvasFACEH2");
    const canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    const canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
    const canvas3 = document.getElementById("canvas3");
    const canvas4 = document.getElementById("canvas4");
    const canvas5 = document.getElementById("canvas5");
    const canvas6 = document.getElementById("canvas6");
    const canvas7 = document.getElementById("canvas7");
    const canvas8 = document.getElementById("canvas8");
    const canvas9 = document.getElementById("canvas9");
    const canvas10 = document.getElementById("canvas10");
    const canvas12 = document.getElementById("canvas12");
    const canvas13 = document.getElementById("canvas13");
    const canvas14 = document.getElementById("canvas14");
    const canvas15 = document.getElementById("canvas15");
    const canvas16 = document.getElementById("canvas16");
    const canvas17 = document.getElementById("canvas17");
    const canvas18 = document.getElementById("canvas18");
    const canvas19 = document.getElementById("canvas19");
    const canvasPIXEL = document.getElementById("canvasPIXEL");

    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const ctxface = canvasFACE.getContext('2d');
    const ctxfaceh = canvasFACEH.getContext('2d');
    const ctxfaceh2 = canvasFACEH2.getContext('2d');
    const ctx2 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
    const ctx3 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
    const ctx4 = canvas3.getContext('2d');
    const ctx5 = canvas4.getContext('2d');
    const ctx6 = canvas5.getContext('2d');
    const ctx7 = canvas6.getContext('2d');
    const ctx8 = canvas7.getContext('2d');
    const ctx9 = canvas8.getContext('2d');
    const ctx10 = canvas9.getContext('2d');
    const ctx11 = canvas10.getContext('2d');
    const ctx13 = canvas12.getContext('2d');
    const ctx14 = canvas13.getContext('2d');
    const ctx15 = canvas14.getContext('2d');
    const ctx16 = canvas15.getContext('2d');
    const ctx17 = canvas16.getContext('2d');
    const ctx18 = canvas17.getContext('2d');
    const ctx19 = canvas18.getContext('2d');
    const ctx20 = canvas19.getContext('2d');
    const ctxpixel = canvasPIXEL.getContext('2d');  

    const canvasElements = [
        canvas, canvasFACE, canvasFACEH, canvasFACEH2,
        canvas1, canvas2, canvas3, canvas4, canvas5,
        canvas6, canvas7, canvas8, canvas9, canvas10,
        canvas12, canvas13, canvas14, canvas15,
        canvas16, canvas17, canvas18, canvas19
      ];
      
      canvasElements.forEach(canvas => {
        canvas.width = canvas.height = 64;
      });
      canvasPIXEL.width = 20
      canvasPIXEL.height = 20 

    const Skin = new Image();
    Skin.onload = function () {
        

                    //FACE
                    ctx.drawImage(Skin, -8, -9, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                    const FACE = new Image();
                    FACE.src = canvas.toDataURL();
                    FACE.onload = function () {
                        ctxface.drawImage(FACE, 57, 57, canvasFACE.width, canvasFACE.height);
                    }
                        
                    
                    //FACE HELM
                        
                        ctxfaceh.drawImage(Skin, -40, -8 , canvasFACEH.width , canvasFACEH.height);  
                    const FACEHELM = new Image()
                    FACEHELM.src = canvasFACEH.toDataURL();
                    FACEHELM.onload = function () {
                        ctxfaceh2.drawImage(FACEHELM, 56, 56 , canvasFACEH2.width , canvasFACEH2.height);
                    }    
                     //BACKHEAD  
                     
                         ctx2.drawImage(Skin, -6, -9 , canvas1.width , canvas1.height);   
                     
                    const FACE2 = new Image()
                    FACE2.src = canvas1.toDataURL();  
                    FACE2.onload = function () {
                        ctx3.drawImage(FACE2, 61, 57 , canvas2.width , canvas2.height);
                    }

                    //BACKHEAD HELM      

                        ctx4.drawImage(Skin, -32, -8 , canvas3.width , canvas3.height);   
                        
                    const FACEHELM2 = new Image()
                    FACEHELM2.src = canvas3.toDataURL();  
                    FACEHELM2.onload = function () { 
                        ctx5.drawImage(FACEHELM2, 61, 56 , canvas4.width , canvas4.height);
                    }
                    //BODY    

                        ctx6.drawImage(Skin, -21, -21 , canvas5.width , canvas5.height);

                    const BODY = new Image()         
                    BODY.src = canvas5.toDataURL();
                    BODY.onload = function () {
                        ctx7.drawImage(BODY, 58, 55 , canvas6.width , canvas6.height);
                    }
                    
                    //RIGHT HAND

                    ctx8.drawImage(Skin, -44, -25 , canvas7.width , canvas7.height);

                    const RIGHTHAND = new Image()
                    RIGHTHAND.src = canvas7.toDataURL();
                    RIGHTHAND.onload = function () {
                        ctx9.drawImage(RIGHTHAND, 63, 57 , canvas8.width , canvas8.height);
                    }

                    //RIGHT SHOULDER

                    ctx10.drawImage(Skin, -45, -24 , canvas9.width , canvas9.height);

                    const RIGHTHAND2 = new Image()
                    RIGHTHAND2.src = canvas9.toDataURL();
                    RIGHTHAND2.onload = function () {
                        ctx11.drawImage(RIGHTHAND2, 63, 56 , canvas10.width , canvas10.height);
                    }

                    //RIGHT HAND OVERLAY

                        ctx13.drawImage(Skin, -44, -42 , canvas12.width , canvas12.height);

                    const RIGHTHANDOVERLAY = new Image()
                    RIGHTHANDOVERLAY.src = canvas12.toDataURL();
                    RIGHTHANDOVERLAY.onload = function () {
                        ctx14.drawImage(RIGHTHANDOVERLAY, 62, 58 , canvas13.width , canvas13.height);  
                    }
                     //LEFT HAND

                        ctx17.drawImage(Skin, -37, -57 , canvas16.width , canvas16.height);

                    const LEFTHAND = new Image()
                    LEFTHAND.src = canvas16.toDataURL();
                    LEFTHAND.onload = function () {
                        ctx18.drawImage(LEFTHAND, 63, 57 , canvas17.width , canvas17.height); 
                    }

                    //LEFT SHOULDER

                        ctx15.drawImage(Skin, -36, -56 , canvas14.width , canvas14.height);

                    const LEFTHAND2 = new Image()
                    LEFTHAND2.src = canvas14.toDataURL();
                    LEFTHAND2.onload = function () {
                        ctx16.drawImage(LEFTHAND2, 63, 56 , canvas15.width , canvas15.height);
                    }

                    //LEFT HAND OVERLAY

                    ctx19.drawImage(Skin, -52, -57 , canvas18.width , canvas18.height);

                    const LEFTHANDOVERLAY = new Image()
                    LEFTHANDOVERLAY.src = canvas18.toDataURL();
                    LEFTHANDOVERLAY.onload = function () {
                        ctx20.drawImage(LEFTHANDOVERLAY, 62, 58 , canvas19.width , canvas19.height);   
                    }

                //------------END OF CUTTING------------
       
                    
                    //FACE

                    const FACEimg = new Image()
                    FACEimg.src = canvasFACE.toDataURL();
                    FACEimg.onload = function () {
                    ctxpixel.drawImage(FACEimg, -49, -53 , 64 , 64);    

                    }

                    //FACE HELM

                    const FACEHELMimg = new Image()
                    FACEHELMimg.src = canvasFACEH2.toDataURL();
                    FACEHELMimg.onload = function () {
                    ctxpixel.drawImage(FACEHELMimg, -48, -53 , 64 , 64);
                    }

                    //BACKHEAD

                    const BACKHEADimg = new Image()
                    BACKHEADimg.src = canvas2.toDataURL();
                    BACKHEADimg.onload = function () {
                    ctxpixel.drawImage(BACKHEADimg, -56, -53 , 64 , 64);
                    }

                    //BACKHEAD HELM

                    const BACKHEADHimg = new Image()
                    BACKHEADHimg.src = canvas4.toDataURL();
                    BACKHEADHimg.onload = function () {
                    ctxpixel.drawImage(BACKHEADHimg, -56, -53 , 64 , 64);
                    }
                    
                    //LEFT HAND OVERLAY      

                    const LEFTHANDOVERLAYimg = new Image()
                    LEFTHANDOVERLAYimg.src = canvas19.toDataURL();
                    LEFTHANDOVERLAYimg.onload = function () {
                    ctxpixel.drawImage(LEFTHANDOVERLAYimg, -50, -44 , 64 , 64)    
                    }


                    //BODY

                    const BODYimg = new Image()
                    BODYimg.src = canvas6.toDataURL();
                    BODYimg.onload = function () {
                    ctxpixel.drawImage(BODYimg, -51, -44 , 64 , 64);    
                    }

                    //RIGHT HAND     

                    const RIGHTHANDimg = new Image()
                    RIGHTHANDimg.src = canvas8.toDataURL();
                    RIGHTHANDimg.onload = function () {
                    ctxpixel.drawImage(RIGHTHANDimg, -58, -44 , 64 , 64);    
                    }

                    //RIGHT SHOULDER      
   
                    const RIGHTSHOULDERimg = new Image()
                    RIGHTSHOULDERimg.src = canvas10.toDataURL();
                    RIGHTSHOULDERimg.onload = function () {
                    ctxpixel.drawImage(RIGHTSHOULDERimg, -57, -44 , 64 , 64);    
                    }
                    
                    //RIGHT HAND OVERLAY      

                    const RIGHTHANDOVERLAYimg = new Image()
                    RIGHTHANDOVERLAYimg.src = canvas13.toDataURL();
                    RIGHTHANDOVERLAYimg.onload = function () {
                    ctxpixel.drawImage(RIGHTHANDOVERLAYimg, -57, -44 , 64 , 64);    
                    }
                    
                    //LEFT HAND      

                    const LEFTHANDimg = new Image()
                    LEFTHANDimg.src = canvas17.toDataURL();
                    LEFTHANDimg.onload = function () {
                    ctxpixel.drawImage(LEFTHANDimg, -49, -44 , 64 , 64);    
                    }
                    
                    //LEFT SHOULDER      

                    const LEFTSHOULDERimg = new Image()
                    LEFTSHOULDERimg.src = canvas15.toDataURL(); 
                    LEFTSHOULDERimg.onload = function () {
                    ctxpixel.drawImage(LEFTSHOULDERimg, -50, -44 , 64 , 64);    
                    }
                    

                //------------END OF DRAWING------------

    // MERGING PIXELART
    
    const canvasSIZE = document.getElementById("canvasSIZE");
    const ctxSIZE = canvasSIZE.getContext('2d');  
    canvasSIZE.width = 1000;
    canvasSIZE.height = 1000;

    ctxSIZE.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

    const PIXELART = new Image();
    PIXELART.src = canvasPIXEL.toDataURL();
    PIXELART.onload = function () {
        ctxSIZE.drawImage(PIXELART, 50, 100 , 900 , 900);
        console.log(canvasPIXEL.toDataURL());
        var PIXERLARTDONE = new Image();
        PIXERLARTDONE.id = "pixelart";
        PIXERLARTDONE.src = canvasSIZE.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById('Pixelart').appendChild(PIXERLARTDONE);
    }
}
}
```

HTML :

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvasFACE" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvasFACEH" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvasFACEH2" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas1" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas4" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas5" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas6" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas7" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas8" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas9" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas10" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas11" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas12" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas13" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas14" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas15" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas16" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas17" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas18" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas19" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvasPIXEL" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvasSIZE" style="display: none;"></canvas>
    <input type="file" id="skin" accept="image/*"/>
<label for="skin" class="skinbtn"><div class="skintext">Upload Skin <i class="fa-solid fa-file-import"></i></div></label>
```

[image: Minecraft Pixelart]

Comment: Why on earth are you using so many separate canvas elements instead of just using one? Heck, why are you using canvas elements at all here, divs with a background colour and appropriate border CSS would probably work just fine here?

Comment: I said the reason above